# Which For loop will execute first, and finish first?

Tags: java

Im confused over the nested loop variant. Somehow these loops give the same result, but I cant wrap my head around it. like, in the second code, it says in the part of col < values[rows], wouldnt the values[rows] = 4(since there are 4 rows)? So im just wondering how does these loops interact and which one executes first and finishes first?

```
 for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)                                    
 {
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
       System.out.print(values[row][col] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();   
}
```

```
for (int row = 0; row < values.length; row++)
{
   for (int col = 0; col < values[row].length; col++)
   {
      System.out.print(values[row][col] + " ");
   }

   System.out.println();    
}
```

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking. It all depends on the size of the 2-dimensional array, and whether it's [jagged](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jagged-arrays) or not.

Comment: look: `values.length == 'rowLength' == 4`, but: `values[row].length == 'colLength' == 3` (length of `row`th row;)

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen i have 2D array with 4 rows, 3 columns in each i.e three values. in the first code of inner for loop, it is col < 3; whilst in the second code inner for loop, it is col < values[row].length. wouldnt the length then be 4 rows, when it should be 3?

Comment: @xerx593 so you mean that value[row].length == colLength? how ??

Comment: @Zerenity put a `System.out.println("row="+row+", "col="+col);` inside your inner `for` loop to see how the variables `row` and `col` changing their values during the execution.

Comment: only "by definition", @Zerenity (you could have named/iterated them visa versa), but having a "2 dim array", you have an outer index (`[*][]`representing "the row index" in your case ... one is free to call/regard it switched) and an "inner index" (`[][*]` representing the columns in your scenario) ..and a rows' maximum "index" is `values.length - 1`, whereas a cols' maximum index is `values[rowIndex].length - 1`

Comment: ..and when `row` is the "outer index",  and `col` the "inner index" ..then `values[row][col]` is the "cell" (value) of row:col.

Comment: ahh i see. basically [row].length means the number of elements in a row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what are you trying to ask here but I guess you just wish to know the difference between the two block of codes.

I'll explain that to you with an simple example:

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        int[][]values = new int[n][m];
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<m; j++){                //read a 5 x 8 array
                values[i][j]= sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Input Array :");
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
                System.out.print(values[i][j] +" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.print("First Code :");
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)                                    
        {
             for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
             {
                  System.out.print(values[row][col] + " ");
             }
            System.out.println();   
        }
        System.out.print("Second Code :");    
        for (int row = 0; row < values.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < values[row].length; col++)
            {
                 System.out.print(values[row][col] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();    
         }    
     }
}
```

Input:

```
5 8 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

Output of the program is:

```
Input Array :3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
First Code :3 3 3 
4 4 4 
5 5 5 
6 6 6 
Second Code :3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

So, as you can see first block works exactly like second block if values.length =4 and values[row].length = 3 otherwise they will give different results. To traverse an array good practice is to go with array.length instead of hard coding the value of length.

Comment: got it, ill make practice of using array.length when running through a 2D array!

Answer (score 2):

In the firs loop:

System.out.print(values[0][0] + " ");

System.out.print(values[0][1] + " ");

System.out.print(values[0][2] + " ");

System.out.print(values[1][0] + " ");

System.out.print(values[1][1] + " ");

System.out.print(values[1][2] + " ");

.......

and so on.... The intern loop will run 4x, since the value of rows = 4. So the output of the intern loop (the col loop) is 4 * 3 = 12 System.out.print(). Get it? Row * Col is the equation that you are looking for. Use it to calc the second code. To help more please show the values defined in values param.

Comment: ahhh I see, so for each row, it fills up the columns first before proceeding to the next row. gotya!

Comment: but i think you mean [0][0], [0][1], [0][2], [1][0], [1][1], [1][2], [2][0]... and so on until [3][2] right??

Answer (score 1):

For the For loops in your first section, you are trying to iterate through a 4 x 3 array. So for each row it iterates through the number of columns specified. It stops at the last column of the last row.

For the for loops in your second section, I think it would be more appropriate when you don't know the values for rows and columns.

The first to finish depends on the length of the row in the second case but is fixed on the first one